# Бот не отвечает

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, python-telegram-bot

Нужно чтобы бот принимал сообщение от пользователся и передавал этот запрос в pymysql и возвращать пользователю. При отправке сообщения боту вылазит предупреждение в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]D:\POSLEDNIYBOT\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\filters\state.py:57: FSMStorageWarning: You haven’t set any storage yet so no states and no data will be saved.
You can connect MemoryStorage for debug purposes or non-essential data.
await state.set_state(self.state)

```
import logging
import config
import importlib
import datetime
import pymysql
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

import sys

importlib.reload(sys)

# log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


# DB CONNECT
class Test(StatesGroup):
    Q1 = State()
    Q2 = State()


bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage == storage)

try:
    db = pymysql.connect(
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=3306,
        user="root",
        password="root",
        database="rusypussy",

    )
    print("Successfull")

except Exception as ex:
    print("HUINYA")


# Поиск id
@dp.message_handler(commands="id")
async def welcam(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    a = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    await message.answer( "Введите телеграм id пользователя для поиска в базе:")
    await Test.Q2.set()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], state=Test.Q2)
async def idSearch(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer( 'Ожидайте пару секунд. Идёт поиск...')
    cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pussy WHERE id = %s", (message.text,))
    db.commit()

    data = cursor.fetchone()




# run long-polling
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Посмотрите ответ на ваш вопрос здесь: **https://qna.habr.com/q/1215830**.
Это относится к вашей проблеме?

Comment: Не смог найти там решение

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вписать:

`dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)`

или

`dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage)`

А у вас в коде два знака =:

`dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage == storage)`

Вроде, должно помочь.